# Avoid LIKE in selection screen PARAMETERS typing

Tags: abap

```
PARAMETERS p_var LIKE varit-variant.
```

The `LIKE varit-variant` addition assists the user with the inclusion of a search help, where a user may enter a report name, and it lists the variants from the `VARIT` table and feeds them to the user.

However, ABAP best practice prohibits using `LIKE` when referring to DDIC types. How can one retain this functionality without using obsolete language elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use type:

```
PARAMETERS: p_var type varit-variant.
```

Comment: And right about that you are! I erroneously thought that the `varit-` addition was tied to the `LIKE` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the below code, if you want to use specific search help.

```
PARAMETERS: p_var TYPE variant MATCHCODE OBJECT h_varid.
```

in this example: h_varid is a search help name.